# Where to put MobXProvider (Provider) in React Native app with multiple stores

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobx

I have trouble understanding the roles of `Provider` and `@inject` in the `mobx-react/native` package.

Most examples using the mobx `Provider` use it to provide a global store. Like so:

```
import { Provider as MobXProvider, observer } from 'mobx-react/native';
import myStore from './stores/myStore.js'

@observer
export default class App extends Component{
    render() {
      return(
      <MobXProvider store={myStore)>
        <NavigationStackOrSomethingElse />
      </MobXBrovider>)
    }
}
```

What exactly is `Provider` for?
As far as I understand, I need it to `@inject` the store into the `props` of subsequent Views. Is there a way to provide and use the store in a single controller? Like so:

```
import { Provider as MobXProvider, observer } from 'mobx-react/native';
import myStore from './stores/myStore.js'

@inject('store')  // <-- doesn't work
@observer
export default class SomeSmallView extends Component{
  render() {
    return(
    <MobXProvider store={myStore)>
      <MyViewThings />
    </MobXBrovider>)
  }
  myAction() {
    this.props.state.doSomeStateThings();
  }

}
```

How are Providers used if multiple stores are used? Are they all provided in the Root screen? Are they provided by the parent screen of the component which wants to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out you always provide all stores you want to use in your app in the beginning:

```
<Provider chatStore={chatStore} wallStore={wallStore}>
  ...
</Provider>
```

And then simply use `@inject` to inject them into components which use them.